# Using printf and scanf functions for doubles in C

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
double itemCost;
double paidMoney;
int changeDue;

printf("How much does the item cost: ");
scanf("%lf", itemCost);

printf("How much did the coustomer pay: ");
scanf("%lf", paidMoney);

changeDue = ( (itemCost - paidMoney) * 100);    

printf("Change due in pennies is: %i", changeDue);
}
```

The program will have a simple inputs like 9.5 which represents £9.50 therefore I am using double to store my values. Also printf and scanf promotes floats to doubles so it does not really matter.

However, when compiling with gcc, I get an error message saying:

```
cashReturn.c:10:15: warning: format specifies type 'double *' but the argument has type 'double' [-Wformat]
```

What does this error mean and why is it popping up?

Comment: you need to pass a POINTER to where you want the parsed value stored: `scanf('%lf', &itemCost)`. otherwise you're passing in the VALUE in that varaible, which will be some random garbage because it was only declared, not initialized.

Comment: Note: better to round than truncate: `int changeDue = round( (itemCost - paidMoney) * 100);`  Other improvements possible too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must pass a *pointer to* a variable of the specified type when using `scanf`.

```
double itemCost;
double paidMoney;
int changeDue;

printf("How much does the item cost: ");
scanf("%lf", &itemCost);
// ----------^

printf("How much did the coustomer pay: ");
scanf("%lf", &paidMoney);
// ----------^
```

Also, you're neglecting to check the return value of `scanf`. *This is not optional!* `scanf`  returns the number of items successfully assigned. If it returns N, but you specified M variables to be assigned, then the last (N-M) variables are left unassigned (and in your case *uninitialized*).

Try something like this:

```
for (;;) {
    printf("How much did the coustomer pay: ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &paidMoney) == 1)
        break;   // success
    printf("Invalid input!\n");
}
```