# my program crashes when i have read in all the scores

Tags: c

This program shuts down/ crashes after i have read in all the judges scores and the compiler doesnt give any warnings. When it has read in all the scores it should print out all the scores and also the highest score the average score and the lowest.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*
Prints out info to the user.
*/
void printInfo(){
    printf("Program information\n");
    printf("The program reads in the number of judges and the score from each judge.\n");
    printf("Then it calculates the average score without regard to the lowest and\n");
    printf("highest judge score. Finally it prints the results (the highest, the\n");
    printf("lowest and the final average score).\n\n");
}
/*
Reads in how many judges the user wants to have.
returns the number of judges.
*/
int readJudge(){
    int tempNumbJudge;
    do{
        printf("Number of judges (min 3 and max 10 judges)? ");
        scanf("%d", &tempNumbJudge);
    }while(3 > tempNumbJudge || tempNumbJudge > 10);
    return tempNumbJudge;
}
/*
Reads in the score from each judge
Parameters:
arr - the array where to put the scores
judges - the number of judges
*/
void readJudgeScore(double arr[], int judges){
    printf("\n");
    double temp = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(i <= judges - 1){
        printf("Score from judge %d? ", i+1);
        scanf("%lf", &temp);
        arr[i] = temp;
        i++;
    }
}
/*
Prints of the score from each judge.
Parameters:
arr - the array with the scores
judges - the number of judges
*/
void printJudgeScore(double arr[], int judges){
    printf("\n");
    printf("Loaded scores:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < judges; i++) {
        printf("Judge %d: %.1f\n", i+1 , arr[i]);
    }
}
/*
Finds the highest score.
Parameters:
arr - the array with the scores
judges - the number of judges
returns the highest score
*/
double findMaxValue(double arr[], int judges){
    double maxValue = arr[0];

    for(int i = 0; i < judges; i++){
        if(arr[i] > maxValue){
            maxValue = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}
/*
Finds the lowest score.
Parameters:
arr - the array with the scores
judges - the number of judges
returns the lowest score
*/
double findMinValue(double arr[], int judges){
    double minValue = arr[0];

    for(int j = 0; j < judges; j++){
        if(arr[j] < minValue){
            minValue = arr[j];
        }
    }
    return minValue;
}
/*
Calculates the average score.
Parameters:
arr - the array with the scores
judges - the number of judges
max - the highest score
min - the lowest score
returns the average score
*/
double findAverage(double arr[], int judges, double max, double min){
    double sum = 0;
    double average = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k < judges; k++){
        sum = sum + arr[k];
    }
    average = (sum - max - min) / (judges - 2);
    return average;
}
/*
Prints out the final results
Parameters:
max - the highest score
min - the lowest score
average - the average score
*/
void printFinalResult(double max, double min, double average){
    printf("\n");
    printf("Final result:\n");
    printf("Highest judge score: %.1f\n", max);
    printf("Lowest judge score: %.1f\n", min);
    printf("Final average score: %.1f", average);
}




int main(){
    int numbJudge;
    double maxValue;
    double minValue;
    double average;

    printInfo();
    numbJudge = readJudge();
    double points[numbJudge];
    readJudgeScore(points, numbJudge);
    printJudgeScore(points, numbJudge);
    maxValue = findMaxValue(points, numbJudge);
    minValue = findMinValue(points, numbJudge);
    average = findAverage(points, numbJudge, maxValue, minValue);
    printFinalResult(maxValue, minValue, average);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler i use is gcc with the flags std=c99 and -Wall

Comment: Just about any beginners book, tutorial or class should have taught you that `scanf` needs *pointers* to where it should write the data. This is accomplished with the address-of operator `&`, as in `&temp`. And considering that you do it correctly in one function but not the other, I'll consider this a typo.

Comment: Exact same error message (and cause) as [Using printf and scanf functions for doubles in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462756/using-printf-and-scanf-functions-for-doubles-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the address of the variable, otherwise how is `scanf()` supposed to write to it?

You need:

```
scanf("%lf", &temp);
```

Also check the return value, I/O can fail.